# Is there an equivalent to Google Sketchup?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, cad

I would like to know the various tools available in Ubuntu similar to Google Sketchup.

I dont like to install Sketchup using wine in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Art of illusion](http://www.artofillusion.org/)

[image]

> Art of Illusion is a free, open source 3D modelling and rendering studio. Many of its capabilities rival those found in commercial programs. Highlights include subdivision surface based modelling tools, skeleton based animation, and a graphical language for designing procedural textures and materials..

[K-3D](http://www.k-3d.org/) (Available in the software center )

[image]

> K-3D's interface uses your platform's look-and-feel, and it's consistent with the applications you already know. New artists will find K-3D easy to understand, and professionals feel right at home. K-3D is intuitive, consistent, and discoverable.

For a  more advanced program you can try

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) (Available in the software center)

[image]

> Blender is a free open source 3D graphics application, available under the GNU General Public License for the Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Microsoft Windows operating systems.
>
> Blender's features include 3D modeling, UV unwrapping, texturing, rigging, water and smoke simulations, skinning, animating, rendering, particle and other simulations, non-linear editing, compositing, and the ability to create interactive 3D applications, video games, animated film, or visual effects. More advanced tools include rigid, realistic body, fluid, cloth and softbody dynamics simulation, modifier-based modeling, character animation, a node-based material and compositing system, and embedded scripting in Python.

Comment: Opps , I didn't notice that you have mentioned Blender =)

Comment: @Binary life it is okay if you did not simply copy and paste from his anwer :).

Comment: @Roland Taylor: I didn't . Actually after I posted my answer , I saw that he had mentioned just the name of Blender without details. Any way not a problem , we are here just for the sake of help :)

Comment: @binarylife I know you didn't ;). I was telling you that you are safe as long as you don't copy :D.

Comment: These all look like artistic/mesh modelling - are there any more appropriate for mechanical modelling?

Comment: there are a problem with The art of illusion, it needs a VM to run java. as it's site says:"Art of Illusion will run on any computer that supports Java 8 or later. "

Answer (score 4):

Check for FreeCAD http://www.freecadweb.org/

"What is FreeCAD?

FreeCAD is a parametric 3D modeler. Parametric modeling allows you to easily modify your design by going back into your model history and changing its parameters. FreeCAD is open source (LGPL license) and completely modular, allowing for very advanced extension and customization."

Answer (score 3):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/)

> Blender is the free open source 3D content creation suite, available for all major operating systems under the GNU General Public License.
>
> Blender's features include 3D modeling, UV unwrapping, texturing, rigging, water and smoke simulations, skinning, animating, rendering, particle and other simulations, non-linear editing, compositing, and the ability to create interactive 3D applications, video games, animated film, or visual effects. More advanced tools include rigid, realistic body, fluid, cloth and softbody dynamics simulation, modifier-based modeling, character animation, a node-based material and compositing system, and embedded scripting in Python.

Comment: If you see a program like Blender the first time you need 5 years to understand how to use, on Google Sketchup you need only 30 min. i think a big difference

Comment: Yah blender is more for art, as are most of the junk programs listed here.

Answer (score 3):

I think the current best answer is https://app.sketchup.com

I know web apps aren't ideal for every use case, but it works well and **is** SketchUp, nothing else is going to be as close to SketchUp as the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Blender, Art of Illusion and K-3D, there is another good 3D modelling software called [Wings 3D](http://www.wings3d.com/). It has a simple interface and doesn't have a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Sketchup 8 is automatically available for "Linux Lite" and "Wine". Simply complete the Linux installation, then  install Wine, Finally under Winetricks, select "install app". Sketchup 8 is on the list in Wine for auto installation.

Answer (score -1):

B-processor is basically a sketchup-like architecture modeling program. All modeling can be done in perspective view, similar hierarchy plus extra options for real architects like distinction between rooms and construction elements.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to find/install and use “B-processor”. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: Particularly relevant as it doesn't 'just work' and their website contains 0 information on how to get it working on Ubuntu. And searching "b processor ubuntu" doesn't give any obvious options. Down voting as it currently doesn't lead to an answer, would upvote if the app is what it appears to be and instructions on how to install were linked to. Which is sad, as I think this is the only real and possibly current answer here.