# I need a 3D Sketchup-like program

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, cad

I'm looking for an alternative to SketchUp for Ubuntu with no luck whatsoever. I'm a heavy user of Blender, but since I can't really script at all, it doesn't fullfill my needs completely. What I'm looking for specifically is an easy tool to design furniture, for example. The tools I need in the program, according to SketchUp, are: exact measurements, ability to draw an object simply by drawing edges in 3D space or at least in 2D, ability to scale, extrude and manipulate with verticies, edges and/or faces in real measurementunits, ability to create a segment in an existing object easily in specified location. For example if I know I want a window in wall, knowing it has to be 1 meter from the ground and 50 cm from the corner, I want an easy way to do that.

What I don't need is calculating anything, running anything. (I only want stacionary designs, no turning wheels, no kogwheels, and if, I don't need to see them move or calculate anything there)

Is there any alternative for SketchUp working this way for Ubuntu?

Comment: This might be a little outdated, but it looks as though the software can still be installed:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/50070/is-there-an-equivalent-to-google-sketchup

Comment: Oh... I looked through the forum and still missed this post, that's weird. Anyway, thanks for that, but none of the program wokrs for me. There is a comment, made by mikiqex "Exactly! In SketchUp I simply draw some 2D lines in 3D environment and ultimately I end up with a 3D model - without dealing with meshes, polygons and 3D primitives."
And that's quite what i need... More like a 2D sketching, drawing program with 3D environment than a real 3D modeling program. :)

Comment: Ah, I missed that comment.  Makes sense, plus I have never used Sketchup, so now it all makes sense to me!  =)

Comment: I've been able to install and use Sketchup using Wine. The only problem I've seen so far is that some plugins don't work.

Comment: Well I know about that possibility. I also have a PC with legal Windows installed, actually. I just wanted to avoid both of these and rather find a free alternative. If I don't, I'll use SketchUp, of course. I just don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

I use FreeCAD, but mostly for part design. http://www.freecadweb.org/

Sweet Home 3D might also be useful to you. http://www.sweethome3d.com/index.jsp

Comment: Sweet Home 3D is only for room designing, not for creating your own designs of the furniture if I recall correctly. I build renaisance-like furniture, and for more complex models, I have to 3D model them first. SketchUp was totally fine, and Blender would be too, but I need it to fit the rooms I'm putting it in and stuff, and changing measures or placing a hole exactly in some point in an object in Blender is quite a pain. 
I'll look deeper on the FreeCAD and then return here and maybe mark your answer as the one I need, but I belive the parametric modeling is not what I want. Thanks anyway.